# Auto Suggest Component › encountered a declaration exception

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

When running `npm test` receive the following js error once my test gets to an enzyme method:

```js
Auto Suggest Component › encountered a declaration exception
```

Using `React started kit` as my boilerplate. Here is my setup:

`setupTests.js`

```js
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15.4';

// This sets up the adapter to be used by Enzyme
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new EnzymeAdapter() });
```

`jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  automock: false, // [boolean]

  browser: false, // [boolean]

  bail: false, // [boolean]

  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!**/vendor/**',
  ],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/coverage', // [string]
  globals: {
    __DEV__: true,
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'node'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|styl|scss|sass|sss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js',
  transform: {
    '\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|json|css|less|styl|scss|sass|sss)$)':
      '<rootDir>/tools/lib/fileTransformer.js',
  },
  verbose: true, // [boolean]
};
```

`package.json`

```js
{
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.13.1",
    "npm": ">=3.10.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.0.0",
    "@rematch/core": "0.6.0",
    "@rematch/select": "0.3.0",
    "ajv": "5.0.3-beta.0",
    "bluebird": "3.4.6",
    "body-parser": "1.18.3",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "enumify": "1.0.4",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-15.4": "^1.3.0",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "foundation-sites": "6.2.3",
    "google-maps-react": "1.0.19",
    "history": "3.0.0",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "io-ts": "^1.8.2",
    "isomorphic-style-loader": "4.0.0",
    "jsrsasign": "6.2.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "material-ui": "0.19.3",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.13",
    "ncp": "2.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "2.2.0",
    "node-localstorage": "1.3.0",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.0",
    "numeral": "2.0.4",
    "pretty-error": "2.1.1",
    "prop-types": "15.6.1",
    "query-string": "6.1.0",
    "rc-slider": "7.0.8",
    "react": "15.3.1",
    "react-autosuggest": "9.4.2",
    "react-content-loader": "3.1.2",
    "react-date-picker": "6.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.3.1",
    "react-ga": "2.2.0",
    "react-modal": "1.9.4",
    "react-onclickoutside": "6.7.1",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "react-split-pane": "0.1.65",
    "react-toastify": "1.7.0",
    "reactable": "0.14.1",
    "recursive-json-key-transform": "0.2.0",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-auth-wrapper": "0.8.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.1.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "1.5.0",
    "source-map-loader": "0.1.5",
    "source-map-support": "0.5.9",
    "universal-router": "6.0.0",
    "uuid": "3.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "3.0.0",
    "write-file-atomic": "1.2.0",
    "xmlhttprequest-ssl": "1.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.3.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.1.5",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.24.7",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chokidar": "^2.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "eslint": "^5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-node": "^0.3.2",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-css-modules": "^2.9.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "extend": "^3.0.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "front-matter": "^2.3.0",
    "gaze": "^1.1.1",
    "git-repository": "^0.1.4",
    "glob": "^7.1.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "isomorphic-style-loader": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.0.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "lint-staged": "^7.3.0",
    "markdown-it": "^8.4.2",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "opn-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "pixrem": "^4.0.1",
    "pleeease-filters": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.2",
    "postcss-calc": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss-color-function": "^4.0.1",
    "postcss-custom-media": "^7.0.3",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^8.0.5",
    "postcss-custom-selectors": "^5.1.2",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-media-minmax": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-nesting": "^7.0.0",
    "postcss-pseudoelements": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss-selector-matches": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-selector-not": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.3",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.3.1",
    "react-deep-force-update": "^2.1.3",
    "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
    "react-error-overlay": "^4.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.2",
    "redbox-react": "^1.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sinon": "^2.0.0-pre.2",
    "stylelint": "^9.5.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^1.0.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^2.3.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "4.25.1",
    "webpack-assets-manifest": "^3.0.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint-js": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ignore-pattern \"!**/.*\" .",
    "lint-css": "stylelint \"src/**/*.{css,less,styl,scss,sass,sss}\"",
    "lint": "yarn run lint-js && yarn run lint-css",
    "fix-js": "yarn run lint-js --fix",
    "fix-css": "yarn run lint-css --fix",
    "fix": "yarn run fix-js && yarn run fix-css",
    "test": "jest",
    "test-watch": "yarn run test --watch --notify",
    "test-cover": "yarn run test --coverage",
    "coverage": "yarn run test-cover && opn coverage/lcov-report/index.html",
    "clean": "babel-node tools/run clean",
    "copy": "babel-node tools/run copy",
    "bundle": "babel-node tools/run bundle",
    "build": "babel-node tools/run build",
    "build-stats": "yarn run build --release --analyse",
    "deploy": "babel-node tools/run deploy",
    "render": "babel-node tools/run render",
    "serve": "babel-node tools/run runServer",
    "start": "babel-node tools/run start"
  }
}
```

`AutoSuggest.test.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import AutoSuggest from './AutoSuggest';


describe('Auto Suggest Component', () => {
  const component = shallow(<AutoSuggest />);
  it('should render without throwing an error', () => {
    console.log(component);
  });

});
```

Thank you in advance